# Project polymer paper-checkbox error

Tags: project, polymer

I've implemented almost all elements of polymer into my website and everything works fine except `paper-checkbox`. I'm using it as follows:

```
<paper-checkbox for><input type="checkbox" id="checkt" name="tgs" /></paper-checkbox>
```

When I check it, it does not work. It does not checks actual value and keeps the input empty. What is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you wrap it with another `input`?

Comment: then how should i put?

Comment: <core-label horizontal layout>
    <paper-checkbox for></paper-checkbox>
    <div vertical layout>
      <h4>Notifications</h4>
      <div>Notify me about updates to apps or games that I've downloaded</div>
    </div>
  </core-label> - Original code looks like, so there should be some input to catch "NAME" for input and i use in PHP:
if(empty($_POST['tgs'])){ //Error }

Comment: Check the paper checkbox demo page.

Comment: checked, see result please :)